# Overloading a bool operator with a member function

Tags: c++, function, struct, operator-overloading, non-static

I have a class like this:

```
    class AI
    {
    private:
        struct Comparator
        {
            bool operator()(const Town* lfs, const Town* rhs)
            {
                return GetHeuristicCost(lfs) > GetHeuristicCost(rhs);
            }
        };
int GetHeuristicCost(const Town* town);
    // constructor and variables
    };
```

`GetHeuristicCost` returns the heuristic from the town parameter to the `exit` of the path.

What I am trying to do is overload the bool operator for a priority queue but it gives me the error

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

I know why it is giving me this error but what I don't know is how to use a nonstatic function inside the `Comparator` struct.

1. `GetHeuristicCost` must be nonstatic
2. I tried moving `GetHeuristicCost` inside the `Town` class to no avail
3. I need to overload the operator with a struct because I need to use two different bool overloadings on the `()` for two different circumstances but with the same parameters (two Towns). In other words I need the struct so I can't do this:

   bool operator()(const Town* lfs, const Town* rhs)
   {
   return GetHeuristicCost(lfs) > GetHeuristicCost(rhs);
   }

Basically I plan on having two structs like this:

```
struct Comparator1
{
    bool operator()(const Town* lfs, const Town* rhs)
    {
        return GetHeuristicCost(lfs) > GetHeuristicCost(rhs);
    }
};

struct Comparator2
{
    bool operator()(const Town* lfs, const Town* rhs)
    {
        return GetHeuristicCost(lfs) + GetTotalCost (lfs, rhs) > GetHeuristicCost(rhs) + GetTotalCost (lfs, rhs);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct instances of the Comparator nested class with a pointer/reference to their "outer" class instance.

```
class AI
{
private:
    struct Comparator
    {
        const AI &outer;

        Comparator(const AI &o):outer(o){}

        bool operator()(const Town* lfs, const Town* rhs)const
        {
            return outer.GetHeuristicCost(lfs) > outer.GetHeuristicCost(rhs);
        }
    };

    int GetHeuristicCost(const Town* town)const;
};

// how to use in code:
AI::Comparator comp(*this);
priority_queue<Town*, vector<Town*>, AI::Comparator> priorityQueue(comp);
```

Comment: I tried using it in one of my functions like this
`Comparator comp(*this);`
`priority_queue<Town*, vector<Town*>, comp>priorityQueue;`

But it gives me the error that comp is not a type name

Comment: priority_queue<Town*, vector<Town*>, AI::Comparator>priorityQueue

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't like the fact that I am not creating an instance of Comparator. It gives me the error that no default constructor exists. Also I don't know if it matters or not but I removed the `const` from `AI &outer` and from `AI &o` because my AI object changes constantly.

Comment: See my edit. Also sure your AI changes constantly, but does GetHueristicCost actually modify it? If you are doing something like A* it is probably a read only operation.